# What's the most concise way to include multiple statements in a Python switch case?

Tags: python, switch-statement

Unlike most other popular programming languages, Python doesn't have built-in support for switch statements, so I usually use dictionaries to simulate switch statements.

I realize that it's possible to include multiple statements inside a case block by defining a separate nested function for each case, but this is fairly verbose, compared to the switch statement in other languages:

```
def switchExample(option):
    def firstOption():
        print("First output!")
        print("Second output!")
        return 1
    def secondOption():
        print("Lol")
        return 2
    options = {
    0 : firstOption,
    1 : secondOption,
    }[option]

    if(options != None):
        return options()

print(switchExample(0))
print(switchExample(1))
```

Is there a more concise way to simulate switch statements in Python, other than the implementation that I've already written? I've noticed that this equivalent JavaScript function is more concise and easier to read, and I want the Python version to be concise as well:

```
function switchExample(input){
    switch(input){
        case 0:
            console.log("First output!");
            console.log("Second output!");
            return 1;
        case 1:
            console.log("Lol");
            return 2;
    }
}

console.log(switchExample(0));
console.log(switchExample(1));
```

Comment: I've tried to include each switch case as a multiline string, and then evaluate each string, but it appears that there's still a syntax error here: http://ideone.com/l8Mhj9 If I can fix the syntax error here, then I'll have a working and concise solution to this problem.

Comment: Why are you testing `options` against `None`?

Comment: @kindall I (incorrectly) assumed that the dictionary would return `None` if there was no match for the case being tested. I'll need to fix this somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

As a fast and easy solution I would simply use if, elif, else to simulate a switch-statement.

```
if option == 0:
    #your actions for option 0
elif option == 1:
    #your actions for option 1
else:
    #the default case
```

Comment: This is a good workaround, although it would be better if I could somehow avoid writing `option ==` for each case (which is why switch statements were invented). This solution is a series of regular conditional statements, so it's still more verbose than a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kind of corny workaround to achieve an approximation of your syntax:

```
def switch(option, blocks):
    for key in blocks:
        if key == option:
            exec blocks[key]
```

Usage:

```
module_scope_var = 3

switch(2, {
    1:'''
print "hello"
print "whee"''',
    2:'''
print "#2!!!"
print "woot!"
print module_scope_var*2'''})
```

Output:

```
#2!!!
woot!
6
```

There's a lot of apostrophes involved, unfortunately, and the indentation looks strange.

Comment: I've found another potential solution. I've tried to return multiline comments from the dictionary (and then evaluate them afterward), but there's still a syntax error here somewhere: http://ideone.com/l8Mhj9